# Hard time with Concurrency in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

So, I'm having a hard time trying to resolve a college problem...
What I need to do is :

I need to create an app that simulates money transfer between accounts using concurrency.
I need to create a method which does this transference in a Bank class like this:

```
transfer(int from, int to, int value)
```

Then I need to create a TransferThread class which manages this transferences.

Problem is I'm getting deadlocks all the time...
What I've done so far:

TransferThread:

```
public void run() {
        int para,de,valor;
        try
        {
            while(!interrupted())
            {
                para = new Random().nextInt(banco.getNUMCONTAS());
                de = new Random().nextInt(banco.getNUMCONTAS());
                valor = (int) (10000 * Math.random());
                if(de == para)
                    continue;
                banco.transfer(de, para, valor);
                sleep(1);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Banco:

```
  public synchronized void transfer(int de, int para, int valor) {
        while(contas[de].getSaldo() - valor <= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e)
            {

            }
        }
        notifyAll();
        contas[de].setSaldo(-valor);
        contas[para].setSaldo(valor);
        System.out.println("Conta num: " + contas[de].getNum() + ". Saldo: " + contas[de].getSaldo());
        System.out.println("Conta num: " + contas[para].getNum() + ". Saldo: " + contas[para].getSaldo());
    }
```

And main:

```
Banco b = new Banco();
        TransferThread[] threads = new TransferThread[2];
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            threads[i] = new TransferThread(b);
            threads[i].start();
        }
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Of course you have deadlocks: you're waiting if the account doesn't have enough money. So if both threads start with an account which doesn't have enough money, they both wait. Why are you waiting in the first place? Shouldn't you simply throw an exception when the transfer is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although banking example is very often used when introducing threading to students, the regular ideas it aims to teach are not the issue in your code.

For some reason you seem to be waiting forever when there isn't enough money in the account, and well, it's not going to magically appear there if both threads wait! They are both simply stuck in infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, problem is, I have tried a lot of stuff but I didn't manage to make it work ! Do you have any idea how to solve it ? Thanks !

Comment: As a comment to your original post states, you shouldn't be waiting when there are no funds. Your system doesn't model a real life scenario. If you went to a bank and wanted to send someone money, would the bank say “YEP, SURE, WE'LL FREEZE EVERYTHING AND WAIT UNTIL YOU HAVE MONEY”. I don't think so. If there are not enough funds on source account, don't wait. Throw an exception if you have to and catch it in a different place to notify the 'user'. Alternatively, if you insist on waiting for funds, you could have a magic method which will spawn funds from heaven and send it to poor accounts.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I tought. My teacher is nuts, so I will see what she wants us to do when this exception occurs. Thanks fpr the answer !

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion -

As you know, a "transfer" involves two things, by two different parties: a "Put" and a "Get".

Consider adding these two methods and synchronizing *them* (instead of the whole "transfer").

Just a thought...